# Enviar array de bytes desde cliente a servidor

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net

Tengo una funcion que por medio de AJAX debe enviar un array de bytes (es una imagen), pero no llega nunca al lado del servidor en ASP.NET
Les muestro mi codigo de lo que tengo por el momento.

AJAX:

```
function ObtenerOByte(data) {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/DeM.aspx/BuscarOByteVW',
        data: { data: data },
        success: function (msg) {

        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

Y el metodo en ASP.NET

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static bool BuscarOByteVW(string data)
{
    var array = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

    return true;
}
```

Tengo un punto de interrupción en el metodo de ASP pero nunca entra ahi, alguna sugerencia?
Sino, otra forma de enviar el array de bytes?

Gracias.

Comment: Podrias intentar codificar la imagen en base64 y decodificarla en asp.net

Comment: @RicardoArana animate a responder amigo, tal vez le funcione, estoy seguro que conoces la función en javascript que permite codificar en base64, no comento mi respuesta porque te estaría robando tu respuesta.

Comment: Por cierto no veo que estes imprimiendo la data obtenida en asp.net en ninguna parte, en tu código real la imprimes en alguna parte?, si no pues... como sabes si de verdad no se carga?

Answer (score 1):

Podrias convertir el archivo en base64

```
function fileToBase64(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result+'');
      reader.onerror = error => reject(error+'');
    });
  }
```

luego llamarla antes del ajax:

```
function ObtenerOByte(data) {

    fileToBase64(data).then( result => {

debugger;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/DeM.aspx/BuscarOByteVW',
        data: { data: result },
        success: function (msg) {

        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
});

}
```

y en tu metodo .net

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public string UploadImage(string data,)
{
    byte[] fileByte = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Image);
  return true;

}
```